# How does rounding work in Number.toFixed function?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

I am coding an API in Java, and the code should behave like another microservice written in Node.

The problematic part written in Node is this:

```
const totalValue =   // this value comes from a query
const risk =         // it is a percentage value from another query

const riskValue = totalValue * (risk / 100);
const available = +(totalValue - riskValue).toFixed(2);

return available;
```

After a few tests I coded the Java API this way:

```
BigDecimal totalValue = ...
BigDecimal risk = ...

BigDecimal riskValue = totalValue.multiply(risk.divide(new BigDecimal(100)));
BigDecimal available = totalValue.subtract(riskValue).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN));
```

Some days later first bug:

```
totalValue = 62822.65
risk = 10
```

Node returns:

```
56540.385.toFixed(2); // "56540.39"
```

This specific number is not rounding half down as I expected it to happen in my Java API.

However, this number is rounding half down:

```
56540.395.toFixed(2); // "56540.39"
```

---

What's the logic behind JavaScript `Number.toFixed(2)`?

How to copy this function behavior in Java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Number.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question completely. If your question is how to round a `double` number up to `2` decimal places, you can do it as follows:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double n1 = 56540.385;
        BigDecimal rounded1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(n1).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        System.out.println(rounded1);

        double n2 = 56540.395;
        BigDecimal rounded2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(n2).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        System.out.println(rounded2);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
56540.39
56540.40
```

Feel free to comment in case you are seeking help regarding something else.

Comment: The problem is that Node is rounding HALF_DOWN for `56540.395` and is rounding HALF_UP for `56540.385`.

Comment: Use `BigDecimal.valueOf` as I've shown in my examples. I do not know `node.js` but this is how it is done in Java.

Comment: I'll try to explain to my boss that the first API is the wrong one, and somehow find an alternative solution to the Number.toFixed function. Because, be it either HALF_DOWN or HALF_UP, it should behave always the same... I just can't understand it randomly using one or another.

Comment: I solved the problem by using [BigNumber](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/) in Node: `BigNumber.set({ ROUNDING_MODE: BigNumber.ROUND_HALF_DOWN });` and then: `new BigNumber(56540.385).toFixed(2)` worked as expected

Answer (score 1):

Referencing the answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash

The problem is, that the exact numbers `56540.385` and `56540.395`does not exist: Floats are always binary based and not decimal based.

Proof:

```
56540.385.toPrecision(18); // returns "56540.3850000000020"
56540.395.toPrecision(18); // returns "56540.3949999999968"
```

So the expression `NUMBER.toFixed(2);` is processed into 2 steps:

1. NUMBER is scanned in transformed to the nearest possible floating point number.
2. `toFixed()` is executed for the transformed number.

And if knowing this mathematics behind the scenes, the result of `6540.39` is correct for both cases.

A possible solution can be to calculate all in cent (factor 100) and then using `(NUMBER/100).toFixed(2)` for the formatted output.

Comment: Already +1... some questions: How would be the code for that factor 100? Also, if I understood correct, the "risk" being divided by 100 would also have the binary based problem? I will have to double-check my "fixed" code now: `risk = new BigNumber(risk).div(100); riskValue = new BigNumber(totalValue).multipliedBy(risk); available = new BigNumber(totalValue).minus(riskValue); BigNumber.set({ ROUNDING_MODE: BigNumber.ROUND_HALF_DOWN }); return +available.toFixed(2);`